# Unable to share S2D Cluster

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage, windows-server-2016

I am creating a session farm for UPD's and seem to be at a loss when it comes to creating the share for the cluster. I double check all my steps from this link

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/remote-desktop-services/rds-storage-spaces-direct-deployment

The very last cmdlet is where it fails when building the share.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-SmbShare -Name UpdStorage -Path C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\Data
New-SmbShare : The resources must be online on the same node for this operation 
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SmbShare -Name UpdStorage -Path C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\Data
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified:     (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare],     CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error -2147018963,New-SmbShare
```

When I go to share the folder manually I recieve this error.

```
The error occured while trying to share Data. The resource must be online on the same node for the operation. 

The shared resource was not created at this time.
```

I have confirmed that both nodes are online, I have attempted this on both nodes to recieve the same error as well. I have added the "SYSTEM" account to full control and inherited all the way down and that has not helped. Anyone have any idea's? This is on a 2016 Server in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

In Failover Cluster Manager, which node is the owner of the CSV? Log on to that node and run the cmdlet there.

Comment: Did that, also failed the CSV over to the other and tried. No go.